# No edit permission on Case created by Workflow when viewed from a Trigger

Tags: trigger, workflow, permissions, before-trigger

The issue: before-insert trigger on Task queries 'UserRecordAccess' and finds that current user doesn't have edit permission to the Case that has just been created by Workflow (Case is assigned to another user). This shouldn't happen as in the Org all users can edit all Cases.

In other words: when a trigger runs, by some reason, current user has edit permissions on all existing Cases in the Org except one. This shouldn't happen as in the Org all users can edit all Cases.

Step-by-step:

1. User U1 creates Adviser Task assigning it to another user U2
2. Workflow "A" (reacting on new record in Adviser Task object) creates a Case
3. Workflow "B" (reacting on new record in Case object) creates an Activity Extension
4. Workflow "C" (reacting on new record in Activity Extension object) creates a Task
5. Task has before-insert trigger that checks if current user has edit permission on the Case, if not - rolls back all changes. And it rolls back.

The issue doesn't come out if user creates Adviser Task assigning to himself.

Output to debug log of all Cases in the Org with their permissions (all from 'UserRecordAccess') shows that current user **has edit permissions on all Cases but the one** created by the Workflow "A".

The org has numerous Sharing Rules, Permission Sets, etc. But, at the end of the ends, **all users can edit all Cases**.

**Upd.**: output to debug log shows that current user has edit permission to all Adviser Tasks in Org, existed and the created one, and to all Activity Extensions, existed and the created one. Current user has edit permission to all Cases but not the one created by Workflow "A".

**Upd.2**: I've created another Workflow also creating a *Case*. If it doesn't populate "Owner" field and new Case stays belonging to current user then the trigger doesn't rollback (ie it finds that current user has edit permission on that Case). If Case's owner is switched to another user then the trigger querying 'UserRecordAccess' finds that current user doesn't have edit permission on the Case. So the issue is definitely because of the "Owner" field. But in this Org all users can edit all Cases! Security settings are applied to object immediately after creation - since correspondent record appears in 'UserRecordAccess', but why is it with 'HasEditAccess=false'?!

**Upd.3**: if to create with a Workflow *an Activity Extension* assigned to another user then current user has edit permission on it, ie 'HasEditAccess=true'. So the issue relates only to *Cases*.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: If you query UserRecordAccess table directly the results combine both permissions and sharing for the relevant record. What OWDs and sharing rules do you have on the org for Case? Please [edit] the question to add these details (rather than commenting).